# Flutter Plugin didReceiveRemoteNotification not work

Tags: ios, plugins, push-notification, flutter

I described didReceiveRemoteNotification in the file of FlutterPlugin, but it is not called when the Push notification is opened.

```swift
public class SwiftSmcPlugin: 
 FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate, FlutterPlugin , FlutterStreamHandler, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MarketingCloudSDKURLHandlingDelegate{
```

I thought that I should use FlutterPluginAppLifeCycleDelegate and implemented it.

However, even if the notification was opened, the plug-in side didReceiveRemoteNotification was never called

```swift
@nonobjc override public func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)  {

        let sdk : MarketingCloudSDK = MarketingCloudSDK.sharedInstance()

        print(userInfo)

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let theSilentPushContent = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            theSilentPushContent.userInfo = userInfo
            let theSilentPushRequest = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:UUID().uuidString, content: theSilentPushContent, trigger: nil)
            sdk.sfmc_setNotificationRequest(theSilentPushRequest)
            print("Notification Data \(userInfo["_od"])")
            sfmc_handle( URL(string: userInfo["_od"] as! String), type: SFMCURLTypeOpenDirect)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }

        completionHandler(.noData)
    }
```

Plugins do not call didReceiveRemoteNotification, but Appdelegate in Runner works

Since I am using salesforce-marketingcloud sdk, I want to realize it with a plug-in.
Is this really possible?

Comment: did you register your app for push notification? Are you testing on real iOS device? did you enable Push notification for app?

Comment: @Gagan_iOS

I registered the app ID and enabled Push notifications in Capbilites.
Certificate did created use sandbox & production.

Push notification testing will be performed on a real iOS device.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to addApplicationDelegate